# 2 primary keys in a table Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 tables in SQL Server. I want to use code first on entity framework and I want to navigate those tables each other. As you see that `KioskBatch` has a composite key and one of the both composite keys as foreign key at the same time, but when try to insert, I get this error:

> The property 'KioskId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

Code:

```
[Table("tblKiosk")]
public class Kiosk
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("Id")]
    public int KioskId { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblCompletionStatus")]
public class CompletionStatus
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblKioskBatch")]
public class KioskBatch
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int KioskBatchId { get; set; }

    public int KioskId { get; set; }

    [Key,ForeignKey("KioskId")]
    public virtual Kiosk Kiosk { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompletionStatus"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? CompletionStatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual CompletionStatus CompletionStatus { get; set; }
}


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblKiosk]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblKiosk] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblKioskBatch]
(
    [KioskBatchId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KioskId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompletionStatusId] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblKioskBatch] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KioskBatchId] ASC, [KioskId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblKioskBatch] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblKioskBatch_tblCompletionStatus] 
    FOREIGN KEY([CompletionStatusId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblCompletionStatus] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblKioskBatch] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblKioskBatch_tblCompletionStatus]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblKioskBatch]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tblKioskBatch_tblKiosk] 
    FOREIGN KEY([KioskId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblKiosk] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblKioskBatch] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblKioskBatch_tblKiosk]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCompletionStatus]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TblCompletionStatus] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: A reference property can't be used as key.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a primary key made of two when mapping, e.g.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<YouEntity>()
       .HasKey(e => new { e.Key1, e.Key2} )
```

Answer (score 0):

For more information read about [Fluent API(HasKey)](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method)

Code sample, if the link is unaccessible.

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasKey(o => o.OrderNumber);
    }
}
public class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    ...
)
```